# How would I / could I obtain an reasonably comprehensive list of domain names?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I know that domain names are constantly changing, and I know there are a *lot* of them, but there is clearly a region of the domain name space which is stable.  How would I go about getting a list, even a very big one?

Such a thing must logically exist, even if it is in a distributed form, because the web's DNS servers resolve names to IP addresses.  So in theory if I could poll all the DNS servers in the world at a moment in time I would have the complete list of mapped names.  Is there a practical way of doing that?

As an aside, does anyone have any good estimates of how many domain names exist at the moment?

Comment: Some stats here: http://www.domaintools.com/internet-statistics/  117M active domains.  If you just need domains and not hosts, then your source data is WHOIS and not individual DNS servers.

Comment: @Sam, in many ways, first, the list is bound to be so large that the only way to handle it is programmatically, second, domain names are of general relevance to programming, especially since most of us are writing code which operates on the web.  I would respond, how is it not?

Comment: Simon if you create an account here on Serverfault with the same details as your StackOverflow one then you can associate and link the two to re-claim your question here.

Answer (score 2):

A starting place would be to download the [DMoz directory](http://rdf.dmoz.org/), and start spidering from there.

Answer (score 0):

[Netcraft](http://www.netcraft.com) run regular surveys of servers/domains and publish a lot of stats and lists. Their [web server survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/web_server_survey.html) could be a good place to start.

As far as I know their data is gathered from a combination of users with  their toolbar installed, people running [ad-hoc server uptime/stats searches](http://uptime.netcraft.com/) and spidering.